# How to stop audio element from overlapping navigation

Tags: html, css

This is my first time dealing with the `<audio>` tag on my website.

I have a navigation bar on the top, with this CSS for it:

```css
/* adapted from tutorialspoint */

#navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #77F697;
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

#navbar li {
    float: left;
}

#navbar li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

#navbar.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

This works just fine with text. However, when I put an audio tag into the site, when scrolling, the audio goes *on top of* the navigation bar, which is not what I want. Instead, I want it to behave like the text, where it slides under.

Here's a mock version of the site that shows the problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="nav_bar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="navbar">
            <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
        </ul>
        <audio controls>
          <source src="mirex_midi.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
              Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
        <p> This is lots of newlines to force the page to scroll:</p>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

And some screenshots of the problem:

[image: Audio element scrolls over]

[image: Text scrolls under]

**How can I get the audio element to scroll under the text?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `z-index: 1;` to your `#navbar` class.

The [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) CSS property sets the z-order of a positioned element and its descendants or flex items. Overlapping elements with a larger z-index cover those with a smaller one.

```css
#navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #77F697;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#navbar li {
  float: left;
}

#navbar li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

#navbar.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navbar">
  <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
</ul>
<audio controls>
          <source src="mirex_midi.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
              Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
<p> This is lots of newlines to force the page to scroll:</p>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a noob myself, but my two cents, kill the float and find an alternative to shift the text. I hate float. Spent hours fighting the same problem once and just gave up and used flexbox instead. Or maybe set the text alignment to left instead of center? I tried that at this end and it seemed to work fine.